# Traefik not work (404) with containers inside a worker node [docker swarm]

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik, docker-network

my problem is the following:

I created a small swarm cluster consisting of 2 simple nodes: a manager and a worker.
On the manager node I installed a stack with a Traefik service and a stack with the services for the Swarmpit dashboard.
On the worker node I installed a stack with wordpress service.
I installed an "overlay" network, named "web", for the correct traefik configuration.

The result is that both the Traefik dashboard and the Swarmpit dashboard work properly. Anything that I put on the worker node is not "recognized" by traefik so it doesn't work. And if I try to reach the web page of the service, error 404 is returned

If I move the wordpress service from the worker node to the manager node it starts working correctly.
In addition I am able to ping from inside the traefik container to the wordpress container via the "web" network and vice versa

What could be the problem?

Below some configurations and logs:

### Traefik **docker-conpose.yml** configuration:

```
version: "3.7"
networks:
  web:
    external: true
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:alpine
    command:
      - --api
      - --docker
      - --logLevel=DEBUG
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.mydomain.cloud
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.backend=traefik.mydomain.cloud
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.port=8080
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - data:/etc/traefik
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
volumes:
  data:
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=x.x.x.x,nolock,soft,rw
      device: :/var/nfs/traefik
```

### Wordpress test **docker-conpose.yml** configuration:

```
version: "3.7"
networks:
  web:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
services:
  app:
    image: wordpress:5.2.1-php7.1-apache
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - web
      - internal
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.mywordpress_test.com
      - traefik.backend=www.mywordpress_test.com
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.port=80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: xxxxx
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: xxxxx
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: xxxxx
    volumes:
      - www:/var/www/html
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - web
      - internal
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxxx
      MYSQL_USER: xxxxx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxx
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql/
      - db_init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker
volumes:
  db_init:
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=x.x.x.x,nolock,soft,rw
      device: :/var/nfs/wordpress_test/db/initdb.d
  db_data:
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=x.x.x.x,nolock,soft,rw
      device: :/var/nfs/wordpress_test/db/data
  www:
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=x.x.x.x,nolock,soft,rw
      device: :/var/nfs/wordpress_test/www
```

### On the **manager** node:

```
    sudo docker node ls

    ID          HOSTNAME    STATUS  AVAILABILITY    MANAGER STATUS  ENGINE VERSION
    xxxxxx *    sw-man-01   Ready   Active          Leader          18.09.6
    xxxxxx      sw-wk-01    Ready   Active                          18.09.6
```

### On the **manager** node:

```
    sudo docker network ls

    NETWORK ID          NAME                        DRIVER              SCOPE
    xxxxxx              bridge                      bridge              local
    xxxxxx              docker_gwbridge             bridge              local
    xxxxxx              swarmpit_net                overlay             swarm
    xxxxxx              wordpress_test_internal     overlay             swarm
    xxxxxx              host                        host                local
    xxxxxx              ingress                     overlay             swarm
    xxxxxx              none                        null                local
    xxxxxx              web                         overlay             swarm
```

### On the **manager** node:

```
    sudo docker network inspect web

    [
    {
        "Name": "web",
        "Id": "vdvnirom26xxxxxx",
        "Created": "2019-06-17T17:59:52.865557645+02:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "xxxxxx": {
                "Name": "swarmpit_app.1.pefyqnzqyhk4lrnkexgs7k4wu",
                "EndpointID": "xxxxxx",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:6f",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.111/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "xxxxxx": {
                "Name": "traefik_traefik.pttpmxhv0fsq02zcew5i2qylw.qfrllyuio7yau74ablv0amqut",
                "EndpointID": "xxxxxx",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:1e",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.30/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-web": {
                "Name": "web-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "xxxxxx",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "xxxxxx",
                "IP": "192.168.2.120"
            },
            {
                "Name": "xxxxxx",
                "IP": "192.168.2.100"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

### On the **manager** node:

```
    sudo docker container inspect [traefik container id]

    [
    {
        ...,
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "xxxxxxxx",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/xxxxxxxx",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "ingress": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "10.255.0.117"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "xxxxxxxx"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "xxxxxxxx",
                    "EndpointID": "xxxxxxxx",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "10.255.0.117",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:ff:00:75",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                },
                "web": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.30"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "xxxxxxxx"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "vdvnirom26xxxxxxxx",
                    "EndpointID": "56a914884xxxxxxxx",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "10.0.0.30",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:1e",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

### On the **worker** node:

```
    sudo docker network inspect web

    [
    {
        "Name": "web",
        "Id": "vdvnirom26xxxxxx",
        "Created": "2019-06-19T18:21:15.839889513+02:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "xxxxxx": {
                "Name": "wordpress_test_app.1.2mbi7i0u9rn14od5fzw1ycbuk",
                "EndpointID": "xxxxxx",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:19",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.25/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "xxxxxx": {
                "Name": "wordpress_test_mysql.1.7qktlbc9ksn164gc292zva12w",
                "EndpointID": "xxxxxx",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:17",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.23/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-web": {
                "Name": "web-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "xxxxxx",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:1a",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.26/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097"
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "xxxxxx",
                "IP": "192.168.2.120"
            },
            {
                "Name": "xxxxxx",
                "IP": "192.168.2.100"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

### On the **worker** node:

```
    sudo docker container inspect [wordpress_test container id]

    [
    {
        ...,
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "xxxxxxx",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": null,
                "9000/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/xxxxxxx",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "wordpress_test_internal": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "10.0.29.35"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "xxxxxxx"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "xxxxxxx",
                    "EndpointID": "xxxxxxx",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "10.0.29.35",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:1d:23",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                },
                "web": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.25"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "xxxxxxx"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "vdvnirom26xxxxxxx",
                    "EndpointID": "cabe06bc3b1c48acxxxxxxx",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "10.0.0.25",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:19",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Traefik has an additional swarm mode flag to support services on different docker nodes. Without this option, it only looks at containers running locally. With the option, the labels need to be on the swarm services rather than individual containers. The traefik compose file needs to look like:

```
  traefik:
    image: traefik:alpine
    command:
      - --api
      - --docker
      # enable swarm mode with the next flag
      - --docker.swarmmode
      # I explictly configure it to watch the docker socket
      - --docker.watch
      # I avoid automatically exposing every container
      - --docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --logLevel=DEBUG
    networks:
      - web
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.role == manager
      labels:
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.mydomain.cloud
        - traefik.docker.network=web
        - traefik.backend=traefik.mydomain.cloud
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.port=8080
```

And then your service would have the labels moved to under the deploy section:

```
services:
  app:
    image: wordpress:5.2.1-php7.1-apache
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - web
      - internal
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.mywordpress_test.com
        - traefik.backend=www.mywordpress_test.com
        - traefik.docker.network=web
        - traefik.port=80
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == worker
```